# scrolling background in one direction only

Tags: html, css

All I want to have a background scrolling effect from bottom to top ,but I dont know how to do so.
 I have tried it using CSS ,but the problem arises here is it scroll in both direction i.e bottom to top and top to bottom.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: change 2s infinite ease-in both;
  background-image: url(http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/background-pictures-2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@keyframes change {
  0%, 100% {
    background-position: 0% 5%;
  }
  5% {
    background-position: 0% 10%
  }
  10% {
    background-position: 0% 15%
  }
  15% {
    background-position: 0% 20%
  }
  20% {
    background-position: 0% 25%
  }
  25% {
    background-position: 0% 30%;
  }
  30% {
    background-position: 0% 35%
  }
  35% {
    background-position: 0% 40%
  }
  40% {
    background-position: 0% 45%
  }
  45% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> This is animating background ...</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by just using the `to` and `from` attributes for the keyframes change. The effect is kind of weird, because the background top and bottom do not fit together...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: change 3s linear infinite;
  background-image: url(http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/background-pictures-2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-position: 0 100vh;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> This is animating background ...</h1>
</div>
```